# javascript: clone a function by assigning it to a variable

Tags: javascript, function, object

Why can't I clone a function in javascript by assigning it to another variable?

E.g:

```
var $ = document.getElementById;
```

Usage attempt:

```
typeof $;  //--> "function"
$('nav');  //--> "TypeError: Illegal invocation"
```

I would think it would just duplicate the function, and still be callable.
Can someone explain why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When just assigning `document.getElementById` to a variable you lose the `this === document` part which you'd usually have when calling it as a method of `document`. To avoid this, use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to explicitly set the `this` context the function uses:

```
var $ = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```

Comment: `bind()` has limited compatibility, it's worth to note.

Comment: It can be shimmed in every browser though. The MDN site I linked even has copy&pastable code for this.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that bind will return a new function (a bound copy), while assigning to a variable just creates a reference.